# Easy way to make an Android+Scala project with IntelliJ 12?

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, proguard

I'm currently trying to create an Android+Scala module in IntelliJ 12.

I couldn't find any up-to-date guide for doing this *easyly*, so I'm trying to find out by myself. I created a simple Android project, added the Scala facet to my module, and enabled Proguard (that should clean the Scala lib in order to make it fit in the APK). I also added a runtime dependency to the scala-library.jar.

But when compiling I get 1300+ errors, like following:

```
ProGuard: [TestScalaAndroid] Warning: scala.reflect.ScalaBeanInfo: can't find superclass or interface java.beans.SimpleBeanInfo
ProGuard: [TestScalaAndroid] Warning: scala.tools.ant.ScalaBazaar: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.tools.ant.Task
ProGuard: [TestScalaAndroid] Warning: scala.tools.ant.ScalaMatchingTask: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You may like the Proguard trick. Straightforward, easy to implement, no sbt or plugins. The whole recipe is on its dedicated [Github repository](https://github.com/yareally/android-scala-intellij-no-sbt-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

take a look at sbt-idea, it integrates with sbt-android plugin
https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/191

Comment: In fact I'm looking for a simple way to do it, ie without SBT or g8 or any ant/mvn file tuning, only with IntelliJ features and plugins. As far as I know this is currently not possible, but as Google announced Android Studio yesterday I suppose this would be easier in the future to integrate Scala with this new IntelliJ-based IDE.

Comment: >  I suppose this would be easier in the future to integrate Scala with this new IntelliJ-based IDE


I'm hoping you're right! Android is so nice, but Java isn't really that fun to work in.

Comment: FYI, SBT-Android includes a lot of default settings for you, including Proguard, and  SBTIdea will generate IntelliJ projects nicely. IntelliJ can build those projects directly, so you just rely on SBT for dependencies and things like that. I'll write a tutorial on all that soon if you're interested ;)

Answer (score 0):

Start with this project:

https://github.com/pocorall/hello-scaloid-maven

Issue `mvn clean package`

Then, you'll get a compiled apk file.

Because this is an ordinary maven project, you can import this project from Intellij (File->Import project...). I use Intellij as a main IDE. It works with a charm.